# Update items in firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-alertdialog

I followed a tutorial on how to update items in firebase, but when I try, it only adds a new item with the new edited name. It doesnt delete the one I was going to update.

Here is my code for the alertdialog (that opens when I long click an item in the listview):

```
private void updateDialog(final String verktøynavn, final String verktøynr, final String verktøytype, final String verktøystatusibil, final String utlånttil, final String verktøystatusutlant) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.endreslette_dialog, null);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final TextView tvverktøynavn = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøynavn);
    final EditText etverktøynavn = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etverktøynavn);
    final EditText etverktøynr = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etverktøynr);
    final Spinner spverktøytype = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spverktøytype);
    final ImageView ivoppdater = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ivoppdater);
    final ImageView ivslettverktøy = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ivslettverktøy);


    dialogBuilder.setTitle(verktøynavn);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    ivoppdater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String navn = etverktøynavn.getText().toString().trim();
            String nr = etverktøynr.getText().toString().trim();
            String type = spverktøytype.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(verktøynavn)){
                etverktøynavn.setError("Navn mangler");
                return;
            }


            updateverktoy(navn, nr, type, verktøystatusibil, verktøystatusutlant, utlånttil);

        }
    });


}

private boolean updateverktoy(String id, String navn, String nr, String type, String statusibil, String statusutlant) {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Verktøy").child(id);


    Verktoy verktoy = new Verktoy(id, navn, nr, type, statusibil, statusutlant);

    databaseReference.setValue(verktoy);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Verktøy endret", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `setValue()` method instead of `updateChildren()` method. If the `id` is different every time when you call the `updateverktoy()`, then a new child will be added, if the `id` the is the same, that child will be overridden. So in order to update a child, you need to use the same `id`, a `Map` that contains the new values that you want to update and then call `updateChildren()` on that particular reference.